# Force inline-type superscript for display equations (but display-type subscript)

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators, subscripts, superscripts

I am trying to create a macro `\jjoin` for a mathematical operator which roughly produces the following behaviour:

Inline: `\bigvee^{(J)}`, subscript (typically `i \in I`) goes in the usual position (as in rendering `\bigvee^{(J)}_{i \in I}`);
Displaystyle:  The `(J)` goes in the same spot as in inline equations, i.e. to the top-right, but the `i \in I` goes below the `\bigvee` as is usual in display style.

I have tried the following definitions for `\jjoin`, to no avail:

- `\mathop{\bigvee{}^{(J)}}` (the `i \in I` appears too far to the right, because the `(J)` part is taken into consideration for determining the middle of the expression);
- `\makebox[0]{\ensuremath{\hphantom{\bigvee}^{(J)}}}\bigvee` (I'm not sure why this fails, but the position of `(J)` is wildly varying; perhaps because `\ensuremath` does not remember whether or not `\jjoin` is invoked in display mode?);

but that's as far as my knowledge of (La)TeX goes.

I have seen [#99538](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99538) but the result is the same as my first attempt above.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\newcommand{\jjoin}{\mathop{\bigvee\nolimits^{(J)}}}

\begin{document}
Inline: $\jjoin \qquad \jjoin_{i\in I}$

Display: \[\jjoin \qquad \jjoin_{i\in I}\]
\end{document}
```

---

*NB. This is my first question here on TeX.SE; I hope that I didn't make too many beginner's errors. Feel free to point them out.*

Comment: Hi! 1) Please provide a full [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackerxchange.com/q/228) (the only beginner's error I think `;)` ). 2) Have you tried `\mathop{\bigvee\nolimits^{(J)}}\limits_{i\in I\phantom{(J)}}` ?

Comment: @tohecz Added MWE; the code you provide works for the specific case, but doesn't provide the required flexibility (I'd like it to work with any subscript).

Comment: That's _four_ great answers -- within the hour! I thank you all for a very warm welcome to a mundane TeXnician.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work exactly as desired:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\jjoin{\@ifnextchar_\jj@in\jj@@n}
\newcommand*\jj@@n{\bigvee\nolimits^{(J)}}
\newcommand*\jj@in[2]{\mathchoice
    {\mathop{\jj@@n}_{#2\phantom{(J)}}}%
    {\jj@@n_{#2}}%
    {\jj@@n_{#2}}%
    {\jj@@n_{#2}}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
Inline: $A=\jjoin B \qquad A=\jjoin_{i\in I} B_i$

Display: \[A=\jjoin B \qquad A=\jjoin_{i\in I} B_i\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. I'll have to remember `\mathchoice`, it's good to be aware of that one.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Just remember never to use multiple `\mathchoice` at once, and never to mix `\mathchoice` with `\mathpalette`. The complexity of the typesetting is exponential (`4^n`) in number of nested instances of these two commands ;)

Comment: If the subscript has a larger width, then the added space (\phantom) becomes too large.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek If the subscript has a larger width, every good typesetter adjusts the overlaps manually anyways, and can therefore take case of this.

Comment: @tohecz: A good typesetter would not like unpredictable spacing.

Answer (score 6):

This answer addresses the remaining problem of [David Carlisle's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117817/16967) that a following symbol clashes with the superscript in the display style version.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\jjoin}{%
  \@ifnextchar_{\@jjoin}{%
    \@ifnextchar\sub{\@jjoin@sub}{%
      \bigvee\nolimits^{(J)}%
    }%
  }%
}
\def\@jjoin_#1{%
  \mathpalette\@@jjoin{#1}%
}
\def\@jjoin@sub\sub#1{%
  \mathpalette\@@jjoin{#1}%
}
\def\@@jjoin#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \sbox0{$\m@th\displaystyle\bigvee$}%
    \sbox2{$\m@th\displaystyle\bigvee\nolimits^{(J)}\kern-\scriptspace$}%
    \sbox4{$\m@th\displaystyle\bigvee_{#2}\kern-\scriptspace$}%
    \mathop{\bigvee\nolimits^{\mathrlap{(J)}}\kern-\scriptspace}_{#2}%
    \dimen@=\dimexpr
      \wd2-\wd0 %
      \ifdim\wd4>\wd0 %
        -.5\dimexpr\wd4-\wd0\relax
      \fi
    \relax
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@
      \kern\dimen@
    \fi
  \else
    \bigvee\nolimits^{(J)}_{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Inline: $A\jjoin X \qquad A\jjoin_{i\in I}X$

\bigskip

Display: $\displaystyle A\jjoin X\qquad A\jjoin_{i\in I}X$

\bigskip

Inline: $A\jjoin_{i\in I\cup K}X \qquad A\jjoin_{i\in I\cup K\cup L}X$

\bigskip

Display:
$\displaystyle A\jjoin_{i\in I\cup K}X \qquad A\jjoin_{i\in I\cup K\cup L}X$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- A following subscript is caught as macro argument if it is preceded by `_`
  or `\sub`.
- `\displaystyle` is detected via using `\mathpalette`.
- Special treatment is only needed, if `\displaystyle` is active and a subscript is given. Then the amount of the overlapping superscript `(J)` is calculated and added as `\kern` after the expression.
- Even numbered box registers below ten can be used for local assignments.
- `\m@th` kill the effect of `\mathsurround`, because we are *inside* a formula.
- `\mathrlap` is not enough to get a superscript without horizontal spacing, because TeX adds `\scriptspace` after sub- or superscripts.
- Because of `\mathpalette` and the measurement of the subscript in display style, the subscript is called five times. Unless the subscript contains global assignments or commands with side effects (e.g. `\write`, `\typeout`), this is usually not a problem. However `\mathpalette`/`\mathchoice` is the *only* way to get the math style in a reliable way, because of TeX's `\over` and similar primitives.

Comment: +1 :-) (so now I voted for everyone except me  on this question:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: +1 for you, because I have based my solution on yours.

Comment: Now you expand `#2` twice :-/ No solution is perfect.

Comment: @tohecz: You are forgetting `\mathpalette` that calls the TeX primitive `\mathchoice` that sets the formula in all four math styles first, before TeX selects the right math style later. Thus the subscript is executed five times.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek `\sbox4{$\m@th\displaystyle\bigvee_{#2}\kern-\scriptspace$}\mathop{\bigvee\nolimits^{\mathrlap{(J)}}\kern-\scriptspace}_{#2}%`

Comment: @tohecz: The subscript is executed *five* times: two times in `\displaystyle` and one time for `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`. Or for times because of `\mathchoice` and one extra in `\displaystyle`. Try: `$\jjoin_{\typeout{inline}}\displaystyle\jjoin_{\typeout{display}}$`

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\mathop{\bigvee{}^{\mathrlap{(J)}}}_{i\in I}$
\bigskip
\[\mathop{\bigvee{}^{\mathrlap{(J)}}}_{i\in I}\]
\end{document}
```

It's easier to control the space after if you change the markup a bit:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\mathop{\bigvee{}^{\mathrlap{(J)}}}_{i\in I}X$
\bigskip
\[\mathop{\bigvee{}^{\mathrlap{(J)}}}_{i\in I}X\]

\newcommand\foo[1][]{%
\mathop{{}\bigvee{}^{\mathrlap{(J)}}}_{#1}\mathchoice
    {\scriptstyle\phantom{(J)}}{}{}{}}

$\foo[i\in I] X$
\bigskip
\[\foo[i\in I] X\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A following letter clashes with the superscript in the display style case.

Comment: Seems I was overexcited. Upon placing `A_i` behind it, the `(J)` overlaps, as Heiko remarks :(.

Comment: @Lord_Farin although beware Heiko's comment: this hides the width of `(J)` completely so you may need to follow it by some space to compensate

Comment: @Lord_Farin updated  oops not right in inline case: will fix....

Comment: I've solved it by passing the subscript to the macro as a parameter, following it by `\hphantom{{}^{(J)}}`. (Hm, that's what you did in your edit too. I'll treat that as a compliment to myself. `:)` (But this doesn't work with inline case `:(`; thankfully, more answerers have arrived.))

Comment: @Lord_Farin fixed fro inline case

Comment: If the subscript has a larger width, then the added space (`\phantom`) becomes too large.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek you've written TeX before I suspect:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- the subscript in the in-line case is higher than it would be if the same expressions were set as ordinary subs and sups.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hmm why?, anyway I give up, ping Heiko instead:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- but heiko's output has different spacing from yours, and looks like what i'd expect from the "ordinary" case.

Comment: @barbarabeeton his solution is better than mine, I'm leaving this one up as his documents and fixes mine.